# Hangman Game extend/append list

Tags: python, list, loops, global-variables, range

I am trying to make a simple hangman game, but I am having trouble displaying the incorrectly guessed letters and the amount of guesses left. Our code can determine which letters are incorrect, but we need to print it out. We tried putting the letters into lists  but we keep getting the error messages 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Additionally, whenever we run guess(), we also keep getting negative guesses remaining, and the game is not ending once the number of guesses reaches 0. Could you help me find the problem?

```
# Hangman Game`

import random
words = open('words.txt').readlines()  # List of words read in from file
secret = ''  # Secret word the player is trying to guess
correctLetters = ''  # Correctly guessed letters so far in secret word
numGuessesRemaining = 0  # Number of incorrect guesses remaining
incorrectGuesses = ''  # String containing incorrectly guessed letters

# Returns a randomly chosen word, all letters uppercased, from the word list
def getNewSecretWord():
    return words[random.randint(0, len(words)-1)].upper().strip()

# Initializes a new game.Sets *secret* to be a new randomly chosen word.Sets *correctLetters* to be a string of '-' characters of the same length as *secret* Sets *numGuessesRemaining* to be 8. Sets *incorrectGuesses* to be empty. Prints out the game board.
def newGame():
    print('Starting hangman game with new secret word')
    global secret
    secret = getNewSecretWord()
    print(secret)
    numGuessesRemaining = 8
    incorrectGuesses = ''
    global correctLetters
    correctLetters = '-' * len(secret)
    printGameBoard(incorrectGuesses,numGuessesRemaining,correctLetters)

# Returns a new string, identical to s, except that the character at the specified index is replaced with the specified new character.
def replaceCharacterAtIndexInString(s,index,newCharacter):
    name = list(s)
    name[index]= newCharacter 
    return ''.join(name)

# Prints out the game board. The game board consists of the set of incorrectly guessed letters, the number of guesses remaining, and the letters guessed correctly thus far in the secret word.
def printGameBoard(incorrectGuesses,numGuessesRemaining, correctLetters):
    print('Incorrect guesses so far: ' + ''.join(incorrectGuesses))
    print(str(numGuessesRemaining) + ' guesses remaining')
    print(correctLetters)

# Converts the specified letter to uppercase and checks if it is in the secret word. If it is not in the secret word, *numGuessesRemaining* is decremented and the letter is added to the string of *incorrectGuesses*. If it is in the secret word, the index of each occurrence of the letter in the secret word is determined and, for each index, characters (hyphens) in the string *correctLetters* are replaced by the specified letter at the corresponding index. After checking whether the letter is in the secret word, the game board  is printed out and a check is performed to see if the game is over.
def guess(letter):
    letter = letter.upper()
    for num in range(0, len(secret)):
        if letter == secret[num]:
            global correctLetters
            correctLetters = replaceCharacterAtIndexInString(correctLetters,num,letter)
            isGameOver()
        else:
            global incorrectGuesses
            wrongGuesses = list(incorrectGuesses) #NonType error message
            letters = list(letter)
            incorrectGuesses = wrongGuesses.extend(letters)
            global numGuessesRemaining
            numGuessesRemaining = numGuessesRemaining - 1
            isGameOver()
    printGameBoard(incorrectGuesses,numGuessesRemaining,correctLetters)

# Checks if the game is over and if so prints an appropriate message. The game is over if all letters in the secret word have been correctly guessed, in which case the player wins, or if the all guesses have been used up, in which case the player loses.
def isGameOver():
    if correctLetters == secret: 
        print ('Congratulations, you win!')
    if numGuessesRemaining == 0:
        print ('You are out of guesses. You lose. The secret word was: ' 
        + secret)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To answer this question requires going through a lot of code. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending disproportionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distil the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the problems**: 
You're seeing "Game Over" whenever you guess a letter. Why?

You forgot to do: `global numGuessesRemaining` after line 21.

You're using the value that you set it to at line 9, so your whole program thinks that `numGuessesRemaining` should be 0, so `isGameOver` correctly says "GameOver"